# PHP Curl GET request doesn't return data

Tags: php, curl, get

This really has me perplexed and other examples on Stackoverflow have not helped.

If I type into the browser :

https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/book/tXMRUSD/P0

I will get an long array of data which is correct.

With the following simple code :

---

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/book/tXMRUSD/P0");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

---

I get :

**bool(false)**

The only difference is my browser fetches the data directly, while the PHP code is on a local website hosted using IIS on windows 10.
I've tried everything and just can't see where I'm going wrong. Any help will be most appreciated. (Ironically, all the authenticated and encrypted POST code works fine and I'm stuck on the easy stuff!)

Comment: check error log if there any error, same code is working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This code it will work!!!!**

```
<?php
$url= "https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/book/tXMRUSD/P0";

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that would work too. After using curl_error(), I saw it was an SSL error, so adding curl.cainfo = c:\php\cacert.pem to PHP.ini, it worked.